# Checking to see if two 2D boolean arrays are equal at a given interval: Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have two 2d boolean arrays, the smaller array (shape) is going over the larger array (world).

I am having trouble to find a method to find out when the smaller array can "fit" into the larger one.

When I run the code it either just goes through the larger array, never stopping, or stops after one step (incorrectly).

```
public void solve() {
    ArrayList<Boolean> worldList=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> shapeList=new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < world[i].length; k++) {
            worldList.add(world[i][k]);
            display(i, k, Orientation.ROTATE_NONE);
            for (int j = 0; j < shape.length; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < shape[j].length; l++) {
                    shapeList.add(shape[j][l]);
                    if(shapeList.equals(worldList)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does shapeList "fit" within worldList if all the values match? For example, if true=true and false=false for the respective locations?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: can you give some example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start with a problem like this is brute force for the simplest case. So, for each index in the `world` list, just check to see if every following index of `world` and `shapes` match.

Notice we only iterate to `world.size()-shapes.size()`, because naturally if `shapes` is longer than the portion of `world` we haven't checked, it won't fit.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    ArrayList<Boolean> world = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Work();
    }

    public Test() {
        world.add(true);
        world.add(false);
        world.add(false);
        world.add(true);

        shapes.add(false);
        shapes.add(true);

        // Arraylists initialized to these values:
        //   world:     T F F T
        //   shapes:    F T

        System.out.println(getFitIndex());
    }

    /**
     * Get the index of the fit, -1 if it won't fit.
     * @return
     */
    public int getFitIndex() {
        for (int w = 0; w <= world.size()-shapes.size(); w++) {
            boolean fits = true;

            for (int s = 0; s < shapes.size(); s++) {
                System.out.println("Compare shapes[" + s + "] and world["+ (w+s) + "]: " +
                        shapes.get(s).equals(world.get(w+s)));

                if (!shapes.get(s).equals(world.get(w+s))) fits = false;
            }

            System.out.println();

            if (fits) return w;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

When we run this code, we get a value of 2 printed to the console, since `shapes` does indeed fit inside world, starting at `world[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the row and column of fitting like this

```
public void fit() {
    int h = world.length - shape.length;
    int w = world[0].length - shape[0].length;

    for (int i = 0; i <= h; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= w; k++) {
            boolean found = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < shape.length && found; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < shape[j].length && found; l++) {
                    if (shape[j][l] != world[i + j][k + l]) 
                        found = false;
                }
            }

            if (found) {
                //Your shape list fit the world list at starting index (i, k)
                //You can for example save the i, k variable in instance variable
                //Or return then as an object for further use
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```